# Brackets empty space to the right

Tags: text-editor, adobe-brackets, live-preview

I'm trying out Brackets code editor, and so far I like it, but the vanilla experience is quite lacking. So I searched some usefull Extensions, and unfortunatelly i'm seing an black space to the right, and i don't know which Extension is causing it, please see print screen below. 
Has anyone ran into this problem? if yes do you know which Extension is causing it and how can I solve the problem?
[image: Blank space to the right]

Just something extra: i'm using Brackets for the live preview, and quick edit features. If you guys know a free editor that does that better please let me know.

Comment: This is not a programming related question...try deactivation and or restarting - extension by extension. And figure it out by yourself.

Comment: You guys have more experience, and I was  hoping someone else ran into this before. Anyway, it was the Outline List extension, in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Outline List extension, i removed it and it's looking fine right now.
Gotta say, the Live Preview in Brackets is awsome, especially because it works on any browser.

Answer (score 2):

Experiencing the same issue, I also concluded that it the Outline List Extension that was causing the extra black space.

However, after updating to current version..

```
Release 1.13 build 1.13.0-17696 (release 49d29a8bc)
```

Extra space issue appears to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

By disabling brackets ouline List extension.this problem is solved..